# how to write data from Database Log to an output in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I'm running a similation where i would lige to know the total amount of time agents spends in a delay block. I can access the data when running single simulations in the Dataset log under flowchart_stats_time_in_state_log

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAn1r.jpg

However i would like to to write the data from block 5 (spraying) to an output in order to store the data when running multiple simulations.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pXd6.jpg

Im guessing that the value reffence should look something like the expression below. It is not working however so i would aprreciate it alot if anybody could help me out or suggest an alternate solution for getting the data.

flowchart_stats_time_in_state_log.total_seconds.spraying;

Btw. Time measures dose not work for this situation since i need to know the total amount of time spend in a block after a 12 hour shift. with time measures i do not get the data from the agents that are still in the block when the simulation ends.

Comment: Are you looking for the time per agent (i.e., min/avg/max per agent), or just the total time this block was processing?  I would not use the database for this, but if you can clarify your metrics of interest, I am sure the community can provide you some good suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking for the total time all agents have spend in the block. So the sum of all process times, including those who are left in the block when the simulation ends after 12 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the goal of summing all processing times, you could solve it mathematically.  Set the output equal to block.statsUtilization.mean() * capacity * time() calculated on simulation end.

For example, if you have a capacity of 1 and a run length of 100 minutes, then if you had a utilization of 50%; that means you had an agent in the block for 50 minutes.  Utilization = time busy / total time.  Because of this relationship, we can calculate how long agents were actually in the block.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to have a variable to track time in block, incrementing when the agents leave.  At end of the run, you would need to call a function to iterate over the agents still in the block to add their time.  AnyLogic allows you to pretty easily loop over queues, delays, or anything that holds agents:

```
for( MyAgent agent : delayBlockName ){
   variable += time() - agent.enterBlockTime;
}
```

To implement this solution, you would need to create your own agent (name it something better than MyAgent) with a variable for when the agent enters the block.  You would then need to then mark the time each agent enters the block.